# Code skips the loop even though the condition evaluates to true

Tags: python, while-loop

I cannot get this portion of my program to enter the while loop. After plugging in values for `poly`, `x_0`, and `epsilon`, the program calculates a value for `ans` using the function `evaluate_poly()` which works correctly and in my specific instance gives the answer `-13.2119`. My epsilon value used is `0.0001`. Since the `abs(ans)` is in fact greater than `epsilon` why is it skipping the loop?

I put a `print ans` statement right below the `x_01 = 0` line to make sure it was calculating correctly before the while loop and also a `print epsilon` statement to make sure it was taking in my `epsilon` value correctly (which it does).

```
def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon):
    """uses newton's method to find a root of a polynomial function"""

    ans = evaluate_poly(poly, x_0)
    x_01 = 0

    while abs(ans) > epsilon:

        Dpoly = compute_deriv(poly)
        Fprime = evaluate_poly(Dpoly, x_01)
        return ans

        x_01 = x_0 - (ans/Fprime)
        print x_01
        return x_01

    print ans
```

Comment: `>>> abs(-13.2119) > 0.0001` returns `True`

Answer (score 2):

You put two return statements inside your loop. When the first one is hit, the function exits instantly only. So, not only is the while loop being exited on the first loop, but the print statements are never being reached.

Answer (score 1):

You have `return ans` inside your loop. So at that point the function will exit, and the `print` will never be reached.

If `ans` is really -13.2119 then it does enter the loop, it just doesn't perform everything in it because of the `return`.

Even if you remove the `return ans` line inside the loop, there is also `return x_01` at its end. So in that case the loop will run at most once, which will make it the same as an `if` statement.

Comment: so if i add the return ans to the end of the function body it will execute the rest of the body? the goal of the program is to find a value of x_0 that will give an ans of < 0.0001 (not sure if that makes any difference to your answer or not lol)

Comment: @BradGalpin: You need to remove the `return` statements from the loop because they will exit the function immediately. But right now `ans` isn't updated inside the loop, so it will run infinitely. You need to update `ans` to the new value in the loop. And you probably want to return x and not `ans` at the end.

Comment: ah ok, i thought the return statement would update ans above the while loop and then cause it to re-evaluate the while loop. also, the print statements in the while loop were only there to help me try and locate where things were/weren't happening. thanks for the help